# store key input Unity

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, store

Im using a dash system based on wasd input in Unity.

```
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))

    {

        if ((Time.time - lastTapTime) < tapSpeed)

        {

            this.Trigger_FDodge();

            Debug.Log("ForDodge");

        }

        lastTapTime = Time.time;

    }



    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))

    {

        if ((Time.time - lastTapTime) < tapSpeed)

        {

            this.Trigger_RDodge();

            Debug.Log("RightDodge");

        }

        lastTapTime = Time.time;

    }
```

Any one of these on their own is fine, but, because I need to be able to dodge in four directions, I hit a problem. While strictly still a double tap, pressing 'W' then 'D' will trigger a dodge, when it should only be triggered with 'WW' or 'DD'.

When I used XNA, there were options for input states, so I could store and compare the last key pressed with the current one.

```
KeyboardState lastKeyboardState = KeyboardState;
```

Does Unity have a way of doing this? I have also asked on Unity forums, but as yet, no-one has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK storing the whole keyboard state isn't support in `Unity3D`. On the other hand you can't neither have a list of all keys pressed during last update, but you have to check explicitely for each key (or axis if you are using them).

So the only thing you can do it's save the last pressed `KeyCode`:

```
KeyCode lastKey;
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
{
  //process input
  if (lastKeyCode == ...)
  {
  }
  lastKey = KeyCode.D;
}
```